# Javascript string replace all span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML string and I want to replace all span that contain replace text class

```
var html = '<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Hello<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Other string charatcter';
```

Expected Output is:

`{{58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5}}Hello{{58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4}}Other string charatcter`

Means:

```
{{span_id}}middle string{{span_id}}
```

Comment: Any attempts from your side ?

Comment: replace span with what? or replace text ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a dummy element and using the DOM api. Any regexp solution to parse/modify HTML strings is trash.

```js
const prepareHtml = html => {
  var fragment = document.createElement('div')
  fragment.innerHTML = html
  for (let span of fragment.querySelectorAll('span.replace_text'))
    span.innerHTML = `{{${span.id}}}`
  return fragment.innerText
}

var html = '<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Hello<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Other string charatcter'

console.log(prepareHtml(html))
// {{58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5}}Hello{{58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4}}Other string charatcter
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to give the span element the `innerText` of it's `id` attribute.

Here you go :

```js
var html = '<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5" contenteditable="false">mcq</span> Hello <span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4" contenteditable="false">mcq</span> Other string charatcter';

$('#container').html(html);

$('.replace_text').each(function() {
  // We iterate over all such elements

  $(this).text('{{' + $(this).attr('id') + '}}'); // We get vaue in the id attribute and add it to the span

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>
```

As you've tagged the answer with jQuery, I've given my solution using the same

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element, set `.innerHTML` to `html`, use `.find()` `$.map()` to iterate `span` elements, return `span` `.id` and `.nextSibling` `.textContent`, call `.join()` with parameter `""` on resulting array to create string from array.

```js
var html = '<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf5" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Hello<span class="replace_text" id="58d4aa82c887136a08dbedf4" contenteditable="false">mcq</span>Other string charatcter';

var res = $.map($("<div>", {html:html}).find("span"), function(el) {
            return "{{" + el.id + "}}" + el.nextSibling.textContent 
          }).join("");

$("body").append(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```